# How to change the value of a Combobox in JavaFX with code in FXML document?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Im quite inexperienced with javaFX and GUI in general but Im trying to change the value of "VehicleTypeComboBox" to "Van" from "Car" when I choose "Ford Transit 3.2L Duratorq TDCi" from another combo box. The combo boxes are populated in the FXML document and the controllers are in the Java file.

Im assuming it has something to do with the combo box is populated in FXML and work is done in the java document.

Java Code for setting the value, the one in question is the last one as the SetValue doesn't work:

```
    package vehiclelistgui;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable{



    @FXML
    private TableView<?> table;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox PresetVehicleComboBox;


    @FXML
    private TextField reg;

    @FXML
    private TextField make;

    @FXML
    private TextField model;

    @FXML
    private TextField engineSize;

    @FXML
    private TextField fuelType;

    @FXML
    private TextField colour;

    @FXML
    private TextField mileage;

    @FXML
    private TextField warrantyName;

    @FXML
    private TextField warrantyAddress;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton hasWarranty;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker lastServiceDate;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker motRD;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker warrantyExp;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox VehicleTypeComboBox;

    @FXML
    private Button submit;

    @FXML
    private Button reset;

    @FXML
    private Button delete;

    @FXML
    private Button backToMain;

    @FXML
    private Button confirmButton;

    @FXML
    private void handleChoiceBoxAction(){
        if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("Kia Sportage 2.4 Theta II")){
            make.setText("Kia");
            model.setText("Sportage 2.4 Theta II");
            engineSize.setText("2.4 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Petrol");
        }
        else if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("Ford Focus RS MK3")){
            make.setText("Ford");
            model.setText("Focus RS MK3");
            engineSize.setText("2.3 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Petrol"); 
        }
        else if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("Nissan Qashqui 1.6i DIG-T 4X2")){
            make.setText("Nissan");
            model.setText("Qashqui 1.6i DIG-T 4X2");
            engineSize.setText("1.6 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Petrol");
        }
        else if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("Nissan Skyline R32")){
            make.setText("Nissan");
            model.setText("Skyline R32");
            engineSize.setText("2.6 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Petrol");
        }
        else if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("Vaxhaull Corsa OPC")){
            make.setText("Vaxhuall");
            model.setText("Corsa OPC");
            engineSize.setText("1.6 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Petrol");
        }
        else if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("Nissan Juke 1.6 DIG-T (Nismo)")){
            make.setText("Nissan");
            model.setText("Juke 1.6 DIG-T (Nismo)");
            engineSize.setText("1.6 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Petrol");
        }
        else if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("Vaxhuall Astra 1.6 SIDI Turbo S/S")){
            make.setText("Vaxhuall");
            model.setText("Astra 1.6 SIDI Turbo S/S");
            engineSize.setText("1.6 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Disel");
        }
        else if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("Volkswagon Golf R32")){
            make.setText("Volkswagon");
            model.setText("Golf R32");
            engineSize.setText("3.6 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Petrol");
        }
        else if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("Toyota AE86 Trueno")){
            make.setText("Toyota");
            model.setText("AE86 Trueno");
            engineSize.setText("1.6 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Petrol");
        }
        else if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("Mercedes C Class AMG")){
            make.setText("Mercedes");
            model.setText("C Class AMG");
            engineSize.setText("6.0 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Petrol");
        }
        else if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("BMW E92 M3 GTS")){
            make.setText("BMW");
            model.setText("E92 M3 GTS");
            engineSize.setText("4.4 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Petrol");
        }
        else if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("BMW E82 M4")){
            make.setText("BMW");
            model.setText("E82 M4");
            engineSize.setText("3.0 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Petrol");
        }
        else if(PresetVehicleComboBox.getValue().equals("Ford Transit 3.2L Duratorq TDCi")){
            make.setText("Ford");
            model.setText("Transit 3.2L Duratorq TDCi");
            engineSize.setText("3.2 litre");
            fuelType.setText("Disel");
            VehicleTypeComboBox.setValue("Van");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        make.setText("Hello World!");
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {


    }




}
```

FXML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="comfirmButton" prefHeight="546.0" prefWidth="793.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="vehiclelistgui.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="793.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <Label layoutX="21.0" layoutY="44.0" text="Vehicle List">
         <font>
            <Font size="21.0" />
         </font>
      </Label> 
      <Label layoutX="595.0" layoutY="95.0" text="Preset Vehicle" />
      <TextField fx:id="reg" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="117.0" promptText="Registration" />
      <TextField fx:id="make" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="154.0" promptText="Make" />
      <TextField fx:id="model" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="190.0" promptText="Model" />
      <TextField fx:id="engineSize" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="227.0" promptText="Engine Size" />
      <TextField fx:id="fuelType" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="117.0" promptText="Fuel Type" />
      <TextField fx:id="colour" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="154.0" promptText="Colour" />
      <TextField fx:id="mileage" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="190.0" promptText="Mileage" />
      <TextField fx:id="warrantyName" layoutX="385.0" layoutY="117.0" promptText="Warranty Name" />
      <TextField fx:id="warrantyAddress" layoutX="385.0" layoutY="154.0" promptText="Warranty Address" />
      <RadioButton fx:id="hasWarranty" layoutX="419.0" layoutY="85.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Warranty" />
      <DatePicker fx:id="lastServiceDate" layoutX="385.0" layoutY="227.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="167.0" promptText="Last Service Date" />
      <DatePicker fx:id="motRD" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="227.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="167.0" promptText="MOT Renewal Date" />
      <DatePicker fx:id="warrantyExp" layoutX="385.0" layoutY="190.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="167.0" promptText="Warranty Expirery" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="VehicleType" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="81.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="167.0" promptText="Vehicle Type">
          <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Car" />
            <String fx:value="Truck" />
            <String fx:value="Van" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
    <value>
        <String fx:value="Car" />
    </value>
      </ComboBox>
      <Button fx:id="submit" layoutX="657.0" layoutY="227.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Submit" />
      <Button fx:id="reset" layoutX="657.0" layoutY="190.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="Reset" />
      <Button fx:id="delete" layoutX="552.0" layoutY="492.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
      <Button fx:id="backToMain" layoutX="627.0" layoutY="492.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Back To Menu" />
      <Label layoutX="245.0" layoutY="57.0" text="Vehicle Type" />
      <ScrollPane layoutX="37.0" layoutY="277.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="723.0" vbarPolicy="NEVER">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1310.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1329.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="97.0" text="Vehicle Type" />
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="95.0" text="Registration" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Make" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Model" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="88.2720947265625" text="Engine Size" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="76.3780517578125" text="Fuel Type" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="60.6219482421875" text="Colour" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Mileage" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="143.6239013671875" text="MOT Renewal Date" />
                        <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="6.3760986328125" text="Has Warranty" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="109.3118896484375" text="Warranty Name" />
                        <TableColumn minWidth="1.22918701171875" prefWidth="141.73388671875" text="Warranty Address" />
                        <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="132.302734375" text="Warranty Expirery" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="140.565673828125" text="Last Service Date" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </content>
      </ScrollPane>
      <ComboBox fx:id="PresetVehicleComboBox" layoutX="566.0" layoutY="116.0" onAction="#handleChoiceBoxAction" prefWidth="150.0">
          <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Custom" />
            <String fx:value="Ford Focus RS MK3" />
            <String fx:value="Kia Sportage 2.4 Theta II" />
            <String fx:value="Nissan Qashqui 1.6i DIG-T 4X2" />
            <String fx:value="Vaxhaull Corsa OPC" />
            <String fx:value="Nissan Juke 1.6 DIG-T (Nismo)" />
            <String fx:value="Vaxhuall Astra 1.6 SIDI Turbo S/S" />
            <String fx:value="Volkswagon Golf R32" />
            <String fx:value="Mercedes C Class AMG" />
            <String fx:value="Nissan Skyline R32" />
            <String fx:value="Toyota AE86 Trueno" />
            <String fx:value="BMW E92 M3 GTS" />
            <String fx:value="BMW E82 M4" />
            <String fx:value="Ford Transit 3.2L Duratorq TDCi" />
        </FXCollections>
          </items>
          <value>
              <String fx:value="Custom" />
          </value>
      </ComboBox>
      <Button layoutX="721.0" layoutY="116.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Confirm" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Main Class:

```
package vehiclelistgui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author vincent
 */
public class VehicleListGUI extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What happens? Can you create a [MCVE] (i.e. narrow down the number of choices in the combo and the number of text fields to the absolute minimum required to show the problem, and post the *complete* code (application class, fxml, and controller) in the question).

Comment: Also, and as something of an aside, you should consider creating a `Vehicle` class, using a `ComboBox<Vehicle>`, and populating it with `Vehicle` objects. That way you can get rid of the ridiculous (unscalable) `if`-`else` construct in the handler.

Comment: @James_D Thank you for taking the time to reply, Ive added all the code you requested but not the minimal, complete and verifiable, i will have to wait till later tonight. By not working, when I select "Ford Transit 3.2L Duratorq TDCi" from a ComboBox called PresetVehicleComboBox, It sets all the text fields correctly, but it doesnt set the value of the VehicleTypeComboBox to "Van" (I have it set to "Car" by defualt.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't get a null pointer exception from that.

Comment: @James_D Im actually getting 2 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, and a null pointer exception. Would you like to to post the output?

Comment: **Always** include in your question details of any error you are getting. The whole point of an error message is that it tells you what is wrong. Presumably `VehicleTypeComboBox` is null?

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
@FXML
private ComboBox VehicleTypeComboBox;
```

in the controller, but you have

```xml
<ComboBox fx:id="VehicleType" ...>
```

in the FXML file.

Comment: Thank you so much, i can't believe i didn't see that.

Comment: @Kannei If you had spent 2 minutes reading the stack trace you probably would have done.